# Como configurar para compilar projeto antes da execução dos testes de contrato em um projeto Java usando Quarkus?

Tags: java, testes, testes-automatizados

No momento, estou envolvido na integração de testes de contrato utilizando o Pact na JVM, porém me deparei com um desafio. A situação atual requer que eu execute o comando `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` no terminal antes de executar os testes. No entanto, estou buscando otimizar esse processo para que a aplicação seja iniciada automaticamente antes da execução dos testes, eliminando a necessidade de executar comandos separados.

No Spring, podemos utilizar a anotação @BeforeClass para facilitar esse processo:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

public class ContractTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpService() {
        // Inicializa o serviço que será testado
        // Aqui pode ser feito um deploy da aplicação, por exemplo
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class);
    }

    // Outros métodos de teste podem seguir aqui
}
```

Essa abordagem nos permite inicializar a aplicação antes da execução dos testes, garantindo que o ambiente esteja configurado corretamente para as validações.

Tentei implementar algo semelhante no projeto, porém sem sucesso. Abaixo estão minhas tentativas:

Configuração da inicialização da aplicação Quarkus antes dos testes:

```
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.h2.H2DatabaseTestResource;

@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
public class QuarkusTestSetup {
    // Esta classe pode ser vazia, pois a anotação é suficiente para inicializar recursos do Quarkus
}
```

Configuração do Maven para executar o Quarkus antes dos testes:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-quarkus</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>./mvnw</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>compile</argument>
                            <argument>quarkus:dev</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Configuração de dependências no arquivo pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Após configurar esses dois arquivos e executar os testes, o teste fica em uma estécie de "loop infinito", o que anteriormente funcionava normalmente.
Aqui está o código de teste:

```
package com.projeto.pact.provider;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.HttpTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.State;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.loader.PactUrl;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.target.Target;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.target.TestTarget;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("ProviderAPI")
@PactUrl(urls = {"src/test/java/com/projeto/resources/pacts/BasicConsumer-Tasks.json"})
public class ProviderTest {  
  @TestTarget
  public final Target target = new HttpTarget("localhost", 8080);

  @State("Empty state scenario")
  public void toEmptyState() {
    System.out.println("GET state");
  }
}
```